# SEOmatic: Change type of mainEntity

Tags: seomatic

With SEOmatic I want to be able to dynamically change the type of my mainEntity, which defaults to "Webpage" and in some cases I want to change it to "Event"

In an older project I did this:

```
{% do seomatic.jsonLd.get('mainEntityOfPage').type('Event') %}
```

But if I dump the mainEntity again, nothing has changed:

```
{% dd seomatic.jsonLd.get('mainEntityOfPage') %}
```

It's still a `nystudio107\seomatic\models\jsonld\WebPage#1`

How can I achieve this?

I'm using Craft 3.4.30 with Seomatic 3.3.35

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you can't just change the type of the `mainEntityOfPage` because there's a unique PHP class for each schema.org type.

What I would typically recommend here is that you set up the mappings via Content SEO (which lets you set up a different `mainEntityOfPage` per entry type) or you use the SEO Settings field to allow for per-entry changing of the `mainEntityOfPage`.

But if you really want to do it dynamically via Twig, you can. You just need to create a *new* object.

```
{% do seomatic.jsonLd.create({
    'key': 'mainEntityOfPage',
    'type': 'Whatever',
{# fill in other properties here #}
}) %}
```

Comment: aaah, providing the key does the trick. thanks!